# Predicting from logit model

Tags: r, regression, glm, predict

I am running a logit model defined this way:

```
diversity_model <- glm(booking_bool ~ df$var_distance + df$var_price + df$var_prop_review_score + 
                             df$var_starrating + srch_hits + min_rating + max_rating + avg_rating + min_review + 
                             max_review + avg_review + min_loc_score + max_loc_score + avg_loc_score + avg_price + min_price + 
                             srch_booking_window + srch_adults_count + random_bool + prop_starrating + prop_review_score + 
                             prop_brand_bool + prop_location_score1 + prop_log_historical_price + position + promotion_flag + 
                             click_bool ,
                           family = binomial(link = "logit"), df)
```

Now, based on the results, I would like to predict using the following code:

```
new.ob = with(df, data.frame(var_distance = mean(var_distance), var_price = mean(var_price), 
                var_prop_review_score = mean(var_prop_review_score), 
                var_starrating = mean(var_starrating), srch_hits = mean(srch_hits),
                min_rating = mean(min_rating),max_rating = mean(max_rating), 
                avg_rating = mean(avg_rating), min_review = mean(min_review), 
                max_review = mean(max_review), avg_review = mean(avg_review), 
                min_loc_score = mean(min_loc_score), max_loc_score = mean(max_loc_score), 
                avg_loc_score = mean(avg_loc_score), avg_price = mean(avg_price), 
                min_price = mean(min_price), 
                srch_booking_window = mean(srch_booking_window), srch_adults_count = mean(srch_adults_count), 
                random_bool = mean(random_bool), prop_starrating = mean(prop_starrating), prop_review_score = mean(prop_review_score, na.rm=TRUE), 
                prop_brand_bool = mean(prop_brand_bool), prop_location_score1 = mean(prop_location_score1), 
                prop_log_historical_price = mean(prop_log_historical_price), position = mean(position), promotion_flag = mean(promotion_flag), 
                click_bool = mean(click_bool)))

predict(diversity_model, newdata = new.ob, type = "response")
```

I get the following as an error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev =     object$xlevels) :variable lengths differ (found for 'srch_hits')

In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 66766 rows
```

Comment: It looks offhand like new.ob has the wrong dimensions for the problem, check that first.

Comment: don't use `df$` in your formula.

Comment: Why do you have more columns in *new.ob* then *df* as predict assumes same dimensions.

Comment: With that many variables, I wonder why you use a logit. Because you quickly end up with significant variables that are nothing else but green jelly beans : https://www.xkcd.com/882/

Comment: They do have 66,000+ observations (although they probably have some highly correlated variables as well -- but that might not matter too much for prediction).

Answer (score 1):

In general you should *not* use `$` to access variables in a model formula (use just the name of the variable, and rely on R to extract it from the data frame passed as the `data` argument).  For convenience, you may be able to use `.` on the left-hand side of your formula, which means "all of the variables in the data frame except the response variable".  For example:

```
dd <- data.frame(state.x77)
fit1 <- glm((Murder>10)~.,data=dd)
```

If you want to compute the prediction at the mean value of all of the variables (this assumes all your predictors are numeric):

```
predframe <- as.data.frame(lapply(dd,mean))
predict(fit1,newdata=predframe)
```